# Florence virtual keyboard won't start

Tags: pi-2, keyboard

I installed Florence on my RPi2 by running `sudo apt-get install florence`. When I try to open it, I get this error:

```
Xlib:  extension "RECORD" missing on display ":1.0".
WARNING: No XRecord extension found
WARNING: Keyboard synchronization is disabled.
FATAL ERROR: Unable to query XKB extension from X server version=0.0 rc=0
If you need help, please rerun with the -d switch (debug)
and send the output to f.agrech@gmail.com

FATAL ERROR: No signal received from parent process. We assume it's dead.
If you need help, please rerun with the -d switch (debug)
and send the output to f.agrech@gmail.com
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was that Florence cannot be run over a VNC connection. When I connected a monitor directly to my Pi, I was able to run it.